# Sunspot:solr - empty response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot-solr

I'm trying to obtain response of solr for a given query. I've checked the solr query interface on localhost:8983 and its working fine, giving the required response to the queries. I want to select the productId field from each response and print it. Following is the code I'm using:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
# encoding: utf-8

require 'rubygems'
require 'solr'

solr = Solr::Connection.new('http://localhost:8983/solr')
response = solr.query('necklace')

puts "the response is:"
#puts response
puts "\n"
response.each do |hit|
    puts hit['productId'] 
end
```

But it does not print anything, my response seems to be empty. How can I fix this

Comment: What are those back slashes for? shouldn't it be `puts hit['productId']` or `puts hit[:productId]` ?

Comment: could you tell me this `puts hit.class`,it will help us to answer fast.

Comment: @RajeshKolappakam : I'm getting no syntax error, but no results either

Comment: @ArupRakshit : doesn't print anything

Answer (score 1):

Try changing line 16 to:

```
  puts hit['productId']
```

Comment: Did you index your data with `rake sunspot:reindex` after configuring `searchable` block in your model?

Comment: @Mattherick:@raw_response="{'responseHeader'=>{'status'=>0,'QTime'=>1,'params'=>{'fl'=>'*,score','q'=>'necklace','wt'=>'ruby','qt'=>'standard'}},'response'=>{'numFound'=>0,'start'=>0,'maxScore'=>0.0,'docs'=>[]}}\n", @data={"responseHeader"=>{"status"=>0, "QTime"=>1, "params"=>{"fl"=>"*,score", "q"=>"necklace", "wt"=>"ruby", "qt"=>"standard"}}, "response"=>{"numFound"=>0, "start"=>0, "maxScore"=>0.0, "docs"=>[]}}, @header={"status"=>0, "QTime"=>1, "params"=>{"fl"=>"*,score", "q"=>"necklace", "wt"=>"ruby", "qt"=>"standard"}}, @response={"numFound"=>0, "start"=>0, "maxScore"=>0.0, "docs"=>[]}>

Comment: @zrl3dx : Nope I though indexing is already done, as the interface is giving results. Do i need to index for sunspot separately

Comment: Yes, sunspot will only by default add new indices from new instances, but won't index everything when you configure it for the very first time (or add new `searchable` fields).

Comment: Your result seems to be empty? @response={"numFound"=>0, "start"=>0, "maxScore"=>0.0, "docs"=>[]}> –.. am I right?

Comment: @Mattherick : I saw that. as zrl3dx pointed out, it may be an issue of indexing. I'm learning how to do that

Comment: @naka: That should be easy, just call rake task, at least if you w'd use `sunspot_rails`, I don't know is it on purpose or not, but you're listed clean `solr`, so probably without sunspot, which is a ruby 'wrapper' around solr for providing easy way of working with solr engine,  but i'm not sure about that.